how to check if df column contains a map key and if contains, put the corresponding value in a new column in pyspark?
"I have a DataFrame with records stored in a particular column. I want to compare each record in that column against a predefined map. If a record contains any of the keys in the map, I want to populate a new column with the corresponding value associated with that key in the map."

Use the join method from DataFrame: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html

Map is a python dictionary. I don't think join is needed here

You can convert to map to a dataframe and then do a join
